# Rank of the concatenation of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

We all know that the sum of two matrix ranks is greater than or equal to the rank of the concatenation of two matrices, so can this property be extended to $3$ or even $4$ matrices?$$\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq \operatorname{rank}(B)+\operatorname{rank}(C)+\operatorname{rank}(D),$$where $A=(B\mid C\mid D)$.

Comment: Presumably you can apply the rule inductively to get the answer you ask?

Comment: Yes, just induct.

Comment: Did you mean to give an example? But I want logical proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the comments a bit, here's what "applying the rule inductively" might look like.

**Claim:** $\operatorname{rank}[A_1 \mid \cdots \mid A_{n-1}\mid A_n] \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{rank}(A_i)$.

*Proof:* Denote $M_n = [A_1 \mid \cdots \mid A_{n-1}\mid A_n]$. The statement trivially holds for $n=1$. If the statement holds for $n \geq 1$, then it follows that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(M_{n+1}) = \operatorname{rank}([M_n \mid A_{n+1}]) \leq \operatorname{rank}(M_n) + \operatorname{rank}(A_{n+1})
\\ = \left[\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{rank}(A_i)\right] + \operatorname{rank}(A_{n+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \operatorname{rank}(A_i).
$$
By induction, we therefore conclude that $\operatorname{rank}(M_n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{rank}(A_i)$ for all $n$.